# How in Aptana 3 add PEP8 check for Python code?

Tags: python-2.7, aptana

How in Aptana 3 add PEP8 check for Python code ?
I cannot add as in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

see [this](http://widerin.org/blog/using-pep8-checks-in-eclipse):

It describes how you can integrate pep8 checks into eclipse and it has a section for aptana studio as well.

This is what the article entails(in case the link breaks):

**Buildout**

I used buildout to generate a pep8 check binary in my ${buildout:directory}/bin directory. I can now use it from command line or run it as an external programm from eclipse.

```
[buildout]
parts = 
    ...
    pep8
    ...

[pep8]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = pep8
entry-points = pep8check=pep8:_main
dirs = ['src/my.product', ]
scripts = pep8check
initialization = sys.argv.extend(${pep8:dirs})
```

After (re)running buildout you should have an pep8check executable in your bin/ folder.

```
daniel:~/sandbox/project/ $ ls -l bin/ | grep pep8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 daniel  staff    408 22 Mar 17:29 pep8check
```

Executing this file runs a [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) check on each file in your-product.package.

```
daniel:~/sandbox/project/ $ bin/pep8check
src/my.product/my/product/expiration.py:26:50: E261 at least two spaces before inline comment
src/my.product/my/product/expiration.py:47:5: E303 too many blank lines (2)
src/my.product/my/product/logger.py:18:17: E202 whitespace before '}'
src/my.product/my/product/logger.py:49:1: W291 trailing whitespace
```

**Using direct eclipse integration**

1. Open External Tools Configuration dialog (you'll find it in `main
   menu Run->External Tools->External Tools Configuration`).
2. You can use several variables to access your executable or working
   directory. Arguments are not required because they were already
   added in buildout configuration.

   If you are using the same buildout configuration as i posted above you should use `${project_loc}/bin/pep8check for executable and ${project_loc}` for working directory.

**Using Aptana Studio 3.0**

Aptana Studio 3.0 is shipped with pydev and many other tools, pep8 is included too. This offers you a much more comfortable way to enable pep8 checks, because you see'll your code analysis result while you're developing code.

1. Open Settings PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis and enable Code
   Analysis in first tab.
2. Go to last Tab and check pep8 path. The path was correct on my
   system out of the box, i just added one ignore rule, multiple rules
   can be splitted by ', '. Read pep8 documentation to get more info
   about these --ignore options.

I hope this helps.